# Jquery UI dialog with autocomplete select box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I need to implement autocomplete select box inside jqueryUI dialog.

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/zcgWa/

Currently dialog is overflowing the select box. (click the select box)
I have found a solution by removing jqueryUI style overflow:hidden.

```
.ui-dialog {
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
padding: .2em;
outline: 0;
}
```

But the overflow is a native dialog style that comes by default, that is why I think it is not the perfect solution. I also have many other dialogs pop-ups accross the project and removing oveflow might cause some of them not to work properly.

Is there any other better solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by appending the `<input>` that represents the dropdown to the wrapper after the autocomplete and tooltip has been created. i.e. Move line 18 of your JS Fiddle

```
.appendTo( this.wrapper )
```

to line 30 (after this):

```
.tooltip({
    tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
})
.appendTo( this.wrapper );
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nA5L2/1/